# ElasticSearch - How do I order aggregations (not results within aggregations)

Tags: elasticsearch

I execute a query which returns some hits, and a bunch of different aggregations which I use to filter the results.

I'm data-binding the results with Knockout to my page and I'd like to be able to specify the order that the filters appear on the page.

There isn't anything within the returned aggregations I can use to sort them so 
the easiest way to do this is simply to control the order that the aggregation sections appear in the results.  How do I do this?

Example below.... I submit a query with multiple aggregations.  I've marked the first four.
The aggregation results I get back aren't ordered how I want though.  How do I specify the order of the returned aggregations (NOT the terms within them...)?

Query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 16,
  "aggs": {
    "Keyword": { **<------ One**
      "terms": {
        "field": "topics",
        "size": 15
      }
    },
    "Audience": { **<------- Two**
      "terms": {
        "field": "audience"
      }
    },
    "Category": { **<-------- Three**
      "terms": {
        "field": "topLevelCategory",
        "size": 15
      }
    },
    "Author": { **<--------- Four**
      "terms": {
        "field": "authors",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    ...
```

Results:

```
    ...
   "aggregations": {
      "Resource": { **<--------- Six**
         "buckets": [
         ]
      },
      "Category": { **<--------- Three**
         "buckets": [
         ]
      },
      "Published": { **<---------- Five**
         "buckets": [
         ]
      },
      "Keyword": { **<------------ One**
         "buckets": [
         ]
      },
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't order them. In general key/value pairs in JSON are considered unordered so I doubt Elasticsearch will add a feature to do so.

If this is a public site, I also strongly recommend you put something between the page and your Elasticsearch cluster for security purposes. Whatever that "something" is, can transform the result and order the aggregation in a list that be bound accordingly at the javascript layer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I already suspected.  Oh, and I'm not exposing my ES cluster to the Internet at all - thanks for the advice.